# preg_replace help - need to replace [list]..[/list] with HTML

Tags: php, html, regex

I can't get my head around this and I could really use some help.

I want to replace text like this

```
[list]line 0
line 1
line 2
[/list]
```

with

```
<ul><li>line 0</li>
<li>line 1</li>
<li>line 2</li>
</ul>
```

It can appear several times in the string and it would be great if it can avoid adding empty list elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my special BBParser. Spent ages on it.

http://pastebin.com/3MRYRd8k

Use it like this:

```
$parse = new bbParse();
$pageContent = $parse->bbtohtml($dbContent);
```

Comment: Thanks, it replaces the [/list] tag but [list] tag stays the way it is. When I remove the \r \n characters it replaces the [list] tag as well but it doesn't insert the <li></li> around every line between these tags.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, it's expecting [*] at the start of every line. That actually makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: How would I use it twice in a single PHP file? If I try to use it twice it reports Fatal error: Cannot redeclare htmltags() (previously declared in bbparser.php:85)

Comment: Move the htmlTags function out from within the function.

Comment: Thanks but then it said the same thing about bbtohtml() so I turned it into a regular function. I fail at OOP. :)

Comment: Are you including the file twice? It should only ever be included once.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('#[list](.*?)[/list]', $data, $list);
$list[1] = explode("\n", $list);
$html = '<ul>';

foreach($list[1] as $li){
   $html .= '<li>'.$li.'</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
```